# Pass google map coordinates from first to second page and show map according to that

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on Ionic application with google maps.
In app we have 2 pages, with some data on it.

1. First page contains google map, by clicking on it redirects to
   Second page.
2. Second page contains dropdown with country list and Selection button.
3. On selection of any country, it fetches its coordinates and redirects to first page
4. So on first page I want to show the map with received coordinates.

Anyone have idea, how to do this.

1. First Page

   ```
   goToMyLocation(){
   this.map.clear();

   // Get the location of you
   this.map.getMyLocation().then((location: MyLocation ) => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(location, null ,2));
     this.map.animateCamera({

     // Move the map camera to the location with animation
     target:{
       lat: location.latLng.lat,
       lng:location.latLng.lng 
     },
       zoom: 17,
       duration: 500
     });

     //add a marker
     let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
       position:{
         lat: location.latLng.lat,
         lng:location.latLng.lng 
       },
       animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.DROP
     });

     //show the infoWindow
     marker.showInfoWindow();

     this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(
       (data) => {
           console.log("Click MAP",data);
       }
     );

     this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_CLICK).subscribe(
       (data) => {
           console.log("Click MAP",data);
           this.navCtrl.push('SelectGeolocationPage');
       }
     );

   })
   .catch(err => {
     //this.loading.dismiss();
     // this.showToast(err.error_message);
     console.log(err.error_message)

   }); }
   ```
2. Second Page

   ```
   setAsMyLocation(Country: any, State: any) {

       coordinatesData // It gives coordinates

       this.navCtrl.push(this.page, {  
                   data: Country,
                   State,
       });
   }
   ```

Above page get coordinates and redirects to first page.

So I want to use those coordinates in first page to show map.

Comment: It is hard to say anything without seeing your code. Can you share what have you done so far?

Comment: Question updated.